# How to "\DoNotIndex \," in a dtx file?

Tags: dtx, literate-programming

I'm using `\EnableCrossrefs` in a `dtx` file. In the index I now have `\,` indexed.
I tried `\DoNotIndex{{\,}}` and `\DoNotIndex{\thinspace}` without success.

Is there a way to prevent the inclusion of `\,` in the index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just putting

```
\DoNotIndex{\,}
```

should work, no need for redundant braces.

If you want to add more things that don't need to be indexed, you can simply add a comma:

```
\DoNotIndex{\,,\addtocounter}
```

Comment: I suspect this doesn't work

Comment: @karlkoeller Wow, that's spooky, this really works! I didn't try this, because i thought this will never ever work! ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't work only for `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: `\#`, `\$`, `\%`, `\^`, `\_`, `\~`, `\ `, and `\&` are also problematic. See [here](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex%2F3540) for explanation and possible workarounds.

Answer (score 11):

`\DoNotIndex{\,}` works by accident:

1. `\DoNotIndex` changes the catcode of `\` to 12 (other) and adds `\,,` to the list of excluded commands, the token register `\index@excludelist`. The second comma is the separator.
2. Macro `\ifnot@excluded` then looks for the string consisting of a backslash `\`, the macro name part and the separator comma `,` in the list for a match using LaTeX's `\@@in` in the end. Because `\,` contains already a comma, the algorithm gets confused does not interpret the comma as macro name, but as separator comma. Therefore `\,` is found in the list of excluded commands.

- Also `\{` and `\}` work with a trick. Because `\DoNotIndex` changes the catcode of the backslash `\`, the curly braces are not properly nested anymore. Also catcode 12 (other) is needed for the curly braces. Thus `\string` helps as the example shows.

An example that shows the exclusion of `\,`, `\{`, and `\}`:

```
% \iffalse
% arara: pdflatex: {draft: yes}
% arara: makeindex: {style: gind}
% arara: pdflatex
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs
\IndexPrologue{}
\DoNotIndex{\,}
\expandafter\DoNotIndex\expandafter{\string\{}
\expandafter\DoNotIndex\expandafter{\string\}}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}%
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\relax \, \thinspace \{ \}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \PrintIndex
% \Finale
```

> [image: Result]