# \DoNotIndex space with l3doc

Tags: l3doc

Consider the following attempt:

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{duck.tex}
%</driver>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}

\begin{document}
\DocInput{duck.dtx}
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \DoNotIndex{^^A
%   \def,^^A Works.
%   \csname\space\endcsname,^^A Doesn't work.
%   \ ,^^A Doesn't work.
% }
% \begin{documentation}
%   \begin{function}{\foobar}
%     Prints out `foo bar'.
%   \end{function}
% \end{documentation}
% \begin{implementation}
% \begin{macro}{\foobar}
%   This is the code for \cs{foobar}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foo{foo}
\def\bar{bar}
\def\foobar{\foo\ \bar}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{implementation}
% \Finale
```

It produces:

[image: 1]

I understand why it produces `\␣` in the 'Symbols' section of the index, but I want to stop this behavior. What should I add to `\DoNotIndex`?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/943

Comment: Link to related question, [literate programming - How to "\DoNotIndex \," in a dtx file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/how-to-donotindex-in-a-dtx-file/124809#124809)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in the doc package. For the moment you can get it suppressed with

```
\expandafter\DoNotIndex\expandafter{\bslash}
```

but obviously that isn't the final solution and will not work the moment a final solution is in place. More details are in the github issue that was opened.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attention and the solution. It would be great if you could notify here when it gets fixed.

Comment: it is fixed in a branch and will soon get merged into latex-dev so the next distribution of latex-dev should have it. In the main release it will show up with 2023-06

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankMittelback!

Comment: @Niranjan close but not quite right :-) under this name it never reached me

Comment: Oops, sorry! For a long time I was having a wrong spelling in my mind.